# Regsvr32 and Desktop authority

Tags: .net, delphi, regsvr32

I am registering a delphi assembly using regsvr32.  We are currently using Desktop Authority to deploy our installation package for the .NET application.  We are needing to use the delphi assembly in our .NET application so i have to register the assembly with regsvr32 with the installation.  Although i have ran into problems if i register from desktop authority using a batch file, or even a exe that calls regsvr32, the assembly crashes when trying to load. I get a COm Exception saying there was an error retrieving Com Class factory Error: 800401f9.  I have registered the assembly locally and it will work fine. I have also tried adding the registry keys directly to the installer and that doesn't work either, same error. Is there a way i can get this working from Desktop Autority or installer?

Comment: The dll you are trying to register with regsvr32 is a win32 dll, right? Could also be missing dependencies. Like maybe it is compiled with runtime packages and missing rtl100.bpl. Have you tried debugging to get more information?

Comment: Yeah i tried debugging but all i get is the ComException.  It shouldn't be missing any dependencies because when i run Regsvr32 from cmd locally it all works.  But if i try anything from the installer or DA it won't work.  and yes it is a win32 dll.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the install as an administrator?  Also make sure that your installer is named **setup** or **install** as the first 5 or 7 characters respectfully.  If not, and installing into VISTA/Win7 then the application installer might not update the registry properly.

Comment: It is running as an admin. It is named setup. We are running win xp currently. It seems so weird that it is causing this problem.